# Removed gems causing migrations to break

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-migrations

I've removed some Gems from my gemfile after experimenting with them for a bit, including running their migrations etc.

Now I can't run migrations in the test environment. I get errors complaining of (for eg) :

```
NameError: uninitialized constant CreateActiveAdminMenus
```

If i comment out the whole migration, the error remains. If i search the whole app, the constant is nowhere else.

How can i fix up my migrations so the removed gem's don't cause a fail?

Comment: It'll be caused by `ActiveAdmin` - have you tried either adding the gem, or searching for the migration?

Comment: if i add the gem back in it will run, but that seems messy.  If i search for the migration and find it and comment it out it still won't run.

Comment: Okay - have you done `bundle install` / `bundle update` when you removed the Gem? If not, it's probably still trying to be loaded :) If you've removed it & update your bundle, you'll not have the gem being called - which will hopefully remove the migration?

Comment: btw it **is** messy - don't settle for anything less

Comment: Open your rails console and type `ActiveAdminMenus` and check if it returns a table structure. It means it is present in your database. Then you can remove it by writing a migration file.

Comment: i'm doing bundle install / bundle update  - it's not that